# Correlation of each row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, relationship, correlation

I am trying to find correlation between the columns here for each row from the table below:

```
nodes   closeness   degree      actual_relays
238     0.622695    0.394077    0.0799
242     0.654735    0.472665    0.0791
247     0.653274    0.476082    0.0673
250     0.648928    0.458998    0.0689
254     0.705788    0.583144    0.1056
259     0.660647    0.486333    0.1125
```

What I want is:

```
nodes   corr values (for each row between the different columns)    
238     corr_value1 
242     corr_value2 
247     corr_value3     
250     corr_value4     
254     corr_value5 
259     corr_value6 
...
```

Where `corr_values` correspond to the correlation of the data of each individual row. Using `df.corr()` or `df.T.corr()` does not give me the intended result. Can someone suggest the way to do this?

[image: For example here I have plotted the closeness and actual values against each other. Some have a stronger relationship between their closeness and actual values, while some don't have the same strength. How do I find this relationship for each node?]

For example here I have plotted the closeness and actual values against each other. Some have a stronger relationship between their closeness and actual values, while some don't have the same strength. How do I find this relationship for each node?

Comment: But how do I get the correlation for each row?

Comment: It does not make much sense to me. Correlation indexes are defined for the whole dataset. Do you want the contribution of each point to the correlation index? Also, which correlation index definition do you want to use?

Comment: yes for the first question. I want to use the horizontal values as the coefficient

Comment: It is like how do the horizontal values are correlated among themselves for each node. Because some nodes might have a better correlation to their respective values vs others who might not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: how about `df.T.corr()`?

Comment: I get a table of how the nodes correlate with each other with almost all of them with values of 0.97~0.99 using the from the table above. But I am trying to explain the relationship for each node between its values of closeness, degree etc. I added a figure with some more explanation.

Comment: But a correlation measures how 2 quantities vary together (it's linked to their covariance). The correlation is not defined for a single value (unless I don't understand what you're trying to do). If you really want to compare the individual values, then the squared difference would work better

Comment: @Nakor this seems to be what I am looking for. But between who and who? Can the correlation coefficient be involved to relate the changes to the overall correlation between two data sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am looking for here is basically the influence of each node in the correlation of the data presented. For that, I need to follow the steps of finding the correlation that can be found [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-calculate-the-correlation-coefficient-3126228) for example. But before summing the values of the product of standardized values,  I use the [unity-based normalization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/how-to-scale-an-array-of-signed-integers-to-range-from-0-to-1) to find how each node is contributing individually to the total correlation of both of the data.